# Grid in Channel Form won't save data

Tags: channel-form, grid

I'm using a channel form to allow readers to submit letters to the editor that can include pictures. Here's the (redacted) code:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="{my_channel}" category="37" return="/site/page/5569" status="closed"} 
<textarea name="body" cols="50" rows="20" class="rich_text"></textarea>
{field:pictures} 
<input type="submit" value="Post" />
{/exp:channel:form}
```

The form seems to work OK. You can enter photos and captions just as you would in the the control panel. But when I save the form, and go to edit the entry in the control panel, all of the entry is there, except for the grid contents, which are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by rebuilding the form from scratch. I'm not sure what the original issue was, but I'm now about to use a Grid in a Channel Form for input.